# How to handle FormData from express 4

Tags: node.js, express, express-4

I tried sending some form data to my node server but `req.body` has none of my form fields the node side

```
 var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var path = require('path')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile('index.html')
})
app.post('/sendmail', function (req, res) {

  const formData = req.body.formData
```

this is what I'm sending from the browser

```
fetch('/send', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: new FormData(form)
})
```

in dev tools I  only see the data passed in the Referer, maybe that is my issue

Referer:http://localhost:3000/?name=&budget=%C2%A31000

Comment: `body-parser` doesn't handle multipart request bodies, try something like [`multer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer).

Comment: @robertklep I see thanks, feel free to add it to answer. Maybe it would be more simple if I just extra the data to JSON? I'm suprised that I can just pass FormData to fetch and its send as multipart.

Answer (score 146, accepted):

`body-parser` doesn't handle multipart bodies, which is what `FormData` is submitted as.

Instead, use a module like [`multer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer).

For example, to retrieve the (regular) fields of a request:

```
const multer = require('multer');
const upload = multer();

app.post('/send', upload.none(), (req, res) => {
  const formData = req.body;
  console.log('form data', formData);
  res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

Comment: thx, know of any utils to take form data and return it as a JSON object (for things like text inputs and the like) for sending via urlencoded

Comment: @SuperUberDuper you probably have to use something like [`formData.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/entries) to build a JS object from the form contents.

Comment: What does happen behind the scene here `upload.fields([])` ?

Comment: If you can't get this to work, try `upload.any()` instead of `upload.fields([])`. You'll probably eventually want to figure out what field specifications you want to put in the array but `any` is a good place to start.

Comment: is there no way to inject it like bodyparser? (`app.use(multer())` or similar)

Comment: @Blauhirn might be difficult with `multer`, but [`express-fileupload`](https://github.com/richardgirges/express-fileupload) can be used like that.

Comment: @Blauhirn lots of options :D

Comment: after spending my whole day looking through 100s of a solution, and nothing work, then he finally saves my day, thank you soo much.

Answer (score 4):

**Try This also**

*Slight improvement of [@robertklep](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37631882/11766145)  answer, can send the response as json*

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const multer  = require('multer');
const upload = multer();

app.post('/send', upload.any(), (req, res) => {
  console.log('data', req.body);
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  res.send(req.body);
});
```

```
npm i multer --save
```

Comment: Don't have much experience with multer, but wouldn't it be better to default to `.none` rather than `.any`?