# formdata is not accepted in node.js APIs?

Tags: node.js

I am writing node.js App. I am able to get data entered from postman via "x-www-form-urlencoded". But When I enter data with "form-data",the data is not accepted in API.I have tried with **app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}))** and **app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}))** . But still it is not working. Is there any way I can accept data via "form-data"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37630419/how-to-handle-formdata-from-express-4) you cannot use `body-parser` for `form-data`.

Instead, you can use a module like [`multer`](https://github.com/expressjs/multer).