# How to post form data using multipart/form-data in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, forms, post, request

I can't get `req.body` when enctype is `multipart/form-data`, but I get `req.body` when `enctype` is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.
main configuration of my server is

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

I want to get `req.body` when `enctype` of form is `multipart/form-data`.
How to do it?

Comment: when enctype is set to `multipart/form-data` you have to use `req.files`

Comment: without uploading anyfiles, I am going to post string data only

Comment: means in the same route, you need to get `req.body` and `req.files`

Comment: I want to post common data without file using multipart/form-data.
is it possible? then how to do it?

Comment: use multipart/form-data when your form includes any <input type="file"> elements.

Comment: yes if you are posting common data then your enctype should be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: `multipart/form-data` is used for uploads(binary data- contents of files) only

Comment: Btw, I have seen in some sample projects using multipart/form-data for common post (without file input) and there are working well.

Comment: You probably want to use multer (https://github.com/expressjs/multer) to handle multipart/form-data , there is a reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37630419/how-to-handle-formdata-from-express-4