# Adding files to same folder with nodeJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I want to add `mp3, lrc, wav, txt` to the server and the folder name would be `title` and all of the extensions mentioned above would have specified names. As seen in the code, the mp3 would be `"vocal.mp3"`.

```
addSong(event) {

    jQuery('#addItemSave').text("Please wait!");

    this._service.addSong(this.authorText, this.titleText, this.durationText, this.genre).subscribe(
        res => {
            this.data.push(res.data[0]);
            this.addSongFilesToServer();
    });
}

private addSongFilesToServer() {
    this._service.addSongFilesToServer(this.titleText,
            this.mp3file, this.lrcfile, this.pitchfile, this.thumbfile).subscribe(
        res => {
            console.log("Done! Now hide loading icon or what ever...");
            jQuery('#addItemSave').text("Save");
            jQuery('#addNewSongDialog').modal('hide');
            jQuery('#addNewSongDialog').find("input,textarea,select")
                    .val('')
                    .end()
                .find("input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio]")
                    .prop("checked", "")
                    .end();
    });
}

addSongFilesToServer(title, mp3, lrc, txt, thumb) {
    let url = this._config.ServerWithApiUrl + "uploadFiles";
    let body : FormData = new FormData();
    body.append('mp3', mp3, "vocal.mp3");
    body.append('txt', txt, "pitches.txt");
    body.append('lrc', lrc, "lyric.lrc");
    body.append('thumb', thumb, "thumbnail.png");
    body.append('title', title);
    this._config.headers.delete('Content-Type');

    return this._http.post(url, body, { headers: this._config.headers })
        .map(res => res.json()).catch(function(err){
            throw err;
    });
}
```

`addSong(event)` is called when a button is pressed on the page and the all of the files that need to be passed on, are being passed on. The only problem here is that `mp3, lrc, wav, txt` go all under different folders with their their, for example `vocal.mp3`.

Just to illustrate, this is what I am getting at the moment :

```
├───songs
│   ├───vocal
│   │    vocal.mp3
│   ├───pitches
│   │    pitches.txt
...
```

And this is what I need:

```
├───songs
│   ├───title
│   │    vocal.mp3
│   │    lyric.lrc
│   │    pitches.txt
...
```

And the server side:

```
Router.post('/uploadFiles', (req, res) => {

    var title = req.body.title || "title";

    var storage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination: function (req, file, cb) {
            var dir = "../songs/" + file.originalname.split('.')[0];
            if (!fs.existsSync(dir)){
                fs.mkdirSync(dir);
            }
            cb(null, dir);
        },
        filename: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, file.originalname);
        }
    });

    var upload = multer({ storage : storage}).any();
    upload(req,res,function(err){            
        if(err){            
            return res.status(500).send({ 
                code: 500, message: 'could not upload file: ' + err, error: err });
        }else {
            return res.status(200).send({ 
                code: 200, message: 'All files uploaded!', err: ""});
        }                     
    });       
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see in the example that you actually coded that way

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        var dir = "../songs/" + file.originalname.split('.')[0];
        if (!fs.existsSync(dir)){
            fs.mkdirSync(dir);
        }
        cb(null, dir);
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.originalname);
    }
});
```

The `file.originalname.split('.')[0]` actually splits the extension and takes the filename.

so it will be `var dir = "../songs/" + title;` plain and simple.

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        ////////////////////////////
        var dir = "../songs/" + title;
        ///////////////////////
        if (!fs.existsSync(dir)){
            fs.mkdirSync(dir);
        }
        cb(null, dir);
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.originalname);
    }
});
```

Also, `body-parser` doesn't handle multipart bodies, which is what FormData is submitted as. So the `req.body.title` will not work.

Check this for reference: [How to handle FormData from express 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37630419/how-to-handle-formdata-from-express-4)
Most probably you will need to send the `title` in another way

Comment: I know I already accepted your answer but why is the folder name always "title" now. It used to get the correct title when inserted but now its always "title". Is it because there is a string "title" added and it is not getting the `req.body.title" ?
Although it used to get it before

Comment: can you check `console.log(title)` and see if you're getting correctly or not.

Comment: edited answer, check if it answers your query or ask another question