# When logging number in input I get "Undefined"

Tags: node.js, forms, express, ejs, body-parser

I'm trying to use body-parser to just log a number I type in an input.

My HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Upload File</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="fileupload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="filetoupload"><br>
        
        <lable>What Grade</lable><input type="text" name="gradeNumber"><br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Heres my Node JS code:

```
const express = require('express');
const formidable = require('formidable');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.get('/fileupload', function (req, res) {
    res.render("upload")
});



app.post('/fileupload', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body.gradeNumber);
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
        var oldpath = files.filetoupload.path;
        var newpath = 'C:/Users/Shubh Computer/Desktop/VSCode/Grades/1/' + files.filetoupload.name;
        fs.rename(oldpath, newpath, function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            res.write('File uploaded and moved!');
            res.end();
        });
    });
});
app.listen(3000);
```

When I run the project I get the value "undefined". I know I've probably done a bad mistake since I'm a beginner. If anybody could help that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37631882/5972355) answer is what you are looking for. Basically the body-parser doesn't support multipart body. By using form, you are sending data under Form Data and not the body. Therefore, when you access req.body.gradeNumber, you got undefined